# Add score for each word on search engine

Tags: mysql, solr, full-text-search, elasticsearch

I am facing a problem and I hope that someone can help me. I have a search engine for searching objects. Each object has many keywords and each keyword has its own score or weight. For example:

- Object A contains keywords: **Travel** (weight is **5.0**), **Visa** (weight is **4.0**).
- Object B contains keywords: **Australia** (weight:**7.0**)

When I search with text: `"travel to Australia"`. The result will be sorted by weight of keyword. In this case, the result is:

- ObjectB
- ObjectA

I have a plan to design database like that, but can't find out any way to order by weight.

```
Object_name    |           Keyword
 ObjectA       |    "Travel:5.0 Visa:4.0"
 ObjectB       |       "Australia:7.0"
```

So are there some search engines (Elasticsearch, Solr...) that can search on keyword field and order by weight of keywords?

Comment: The question is: how do you plan on indexing/storing the weight. Where do you keep that number?

Comment: Yes, For example: Im using text mining to get keywords of a description of one product. There are some important keywords and I wanna mark them for improving searching results. Where cant i store them?

Comment: you want by keyword and not by field?like name is field and Australia is keyword

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add weight on searched terms but you can boost the pertinence of certain queries.

In that case, you would probably have to write queries for each specific word and boost each query accordingly. That being said I don't really see a use case where a specific word has more weight than an another, since it should be a free search based on keywords. You're probably better of splitting those values in different fields which you would query by using different queries with different boosting scores.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, as an exotic solution, [this token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-delimited-payload-tokenfilter.html) where, with each word you can specify a payload.

Afterwards, you can [retrieve that payload in scripts](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-advanced-scripting.html#_term_positions_offsets_and_payloads) and use it for scoring.

Other than that, you can add a boost at search time, through various ways, in your queries directly.